# Issue setting up richfaes 4

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

i have been working on richfaces 3.3.3 for past 6 moths, and after seeing few components in RF 4, i thought to upgrade it to 4.

My project is well set of 3.3.3, and when i followed the instructions said on RF page and added all the 4 jars in my classpath, it threw problem saying

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory

Plz help

Comment: Pls show configuration files. Is it JSF 2?

Answer (score 0):

Rich faces 4.0 requires some third side jars:

- Google guava library
- cssparser library from http://sourceforge.net/projects/cssparser/
- sac library ( I take it from there: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/w3c/css/sac/1.3/sac-1.3.jar )

Comment: Thanks maks, but i have all required jars in my project classpath